# how to remove white borders from an UIImageView

Tags: xcode, image, swift, uistoryboard, photoshop

I have an application , where I drag a circular UIImageView on top of another UIImageView , and since   a circle could never be squared ,  the white borders of the image must show , so I wonder if there is a way to remove those borders or to hide them (not by making them have the same color ).

Comment: Are you basically asking if you can turn a UIImageView into a circle, because i can give you the code for that. I just don't quite understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am expecting that you are looking for image masking feature. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049/how-to-mask-images-with-core-graphics-in-ios) and [this one](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html) too. Both of them uses CoreGraphics frame functions and are really quicker in response.

Please note that it is not the Swift version but will give you atleast a starter.

Comment: Your answer did work for me , but i think it's kind of long to mask an image , actually I have found that corner radius have did the same thing but with less code, but nevertheless I have finally understood what masking means

Answer (score 1):

try to set the `image.layer.borderWidth = 0`

(this is the swift version)

Comment: I have tried your code , I think you forgot to put the layer property though , and the border width didn't help me

Comment: Well that was actually no real code you should take, just a suggestion. But sorry that did not work

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your problem?